# Error 0x80070570 while installing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, windows-installation

I'm following [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1245432/installing-windows-on-secondary-hard-disk) to install Windows 10 on a new drive.

I created a bootable USB drive using the `Win10_1803_English_x64.iso` image, once with WoeUSB, and once manually, but the installation failed each time. The result was the following error message at around the 10% mark:

`Windows cannot install required files. The file may be corrupt or missing. Make sure all files required are available, and restart the installation.
Error code : 0x80075070`

The ISO file seems to be valid - I've checked its checksum.

How can I complete the installation?

Comment: See this page...https://www.diskgenius.com/how-to/fix-error-code-0x80070570.php

Comment: Better use the official Windows Media tool.

Comment: Rufus is a best utility to make bootable USB. But from the error message ISO is a bad one or you have troubles writing to the disk.